# Speech recognition engines on server. Sphinx VS .Net voice recognition

Tags: .net, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

im a `.Net(Asp.Net)` developer and i desperately need to use `speech recognition` in one of my websites
i searched for speech recognition engines and so far i have come across major 2

```
1. Sphinx
```

`2. .Net Voice recognition`
but the problem is that where ever i read about any of the 2 platforms
i found that .Net's alternative requires training before continuous dictation and i tend to prefer this one because im already a .Net developer.
and no where could i find a comparison between the two. 
i wont mind developing a a wrapper for sphinx in .Net or using one of several which are already available
**but is it worth it?

a link where comparison is present? 
OR someone who might have used both of the frameworks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to compare, CMUSphinx is an open source flexible framework which lets you develop complex speech to text application with less resouces and without internet connection. It has several C# wrappers and being a C library it can be wrapped in any language.

If you are looking for a solution which you can actually modify and tune according to the application needs, CMUSphinx is the only choice.

Comment: can u name any .net wrappers for sphinx.. i cant find any.. :( thankx

Comment: You have a great chance to develop your own one